# Javascript - Manipulating certain checkpoints with differnet names from url

Tags: javascript, html, url, checkbox

I have a website with checkboxes in the html:

```
<input onclick="markAsChanged(this); toggleApproveDeny(this);" name="2c9923914b887d47014c9b30b1bb37a1_approveChk" type="checkbox">

<input onclick="markAsChanged(this); toggleApproveDeny(this);" name="2c9923914b887d47014c9b30b1bb37a1_denyChk" type="checkbox">

<input onclick="markAsChanged(this); toggleApproveDeny(this);" name="2c9923914b887d47014c9b8b4f0337df_approveChk" type="checkbox">

<input onclick="markAsChanged(this); toggleApproveDeny(this);" name="2c9923914b887d47014c9b8b4f0337df_denyChk" type="checkbox">
```

I need a line/script that will 'check' all the boxes with '_approveChk' and leave the others unchecked.
Is there a way to do this in url "javascript:alert();" style?
or a way to call a javascript script stored locally through the url?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could have been more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Is there a way to do this in url "javascript:alert();" style?` Yes but I wouldn't recommend it. Since you asked though:

```
javascript:(function(){ var l=document.getElementsByTagName('input'); for(var i=0; i<l.length; i++) if((''+l[i].name).indexOf('_approveChk')) l[i].checked=true })()
```

This is not the recommend way of doing this sort of thing and if you want include this on lots of links bear in mind that it will may significantly increase the size of your webpage.

Comment: modified to: 
javascript:(function(){ var l=document.getElementsByTagName('input'); for(var i=0; i<l.length; i++) if((''+l[i].name).indexOf('_approveChk')>1) (l[i].checked=true) })()
and it's working exaclty as wanted :)

Comment: If anybody comes across this and is having similar issues I ended up using:
`javascript:(function(){var l=document.getElementsByTagName('input'); for(var i=0; i<l.length; i++) if((''+l[i].name).indexOf('_approveChk')>1) {markAsChanged(l[i]); toggleApproveDeny(l[i]); l[i].checked=true;}})()`